# uploading files greater than 1MB = connection resets

Tags: apache-2.2, php, nginx

I'm using nginx on the frontend as "proxy cache" and apache on the backend, i've set my PHP settings to the following:

```
error_log = /var/www/site1/php_error.log
error_reporting = 22527
file_uploads = On
log_errors = On
max_execution_time = 0
max_file_uploads = 20
max_input_time = -1
memory_limit = 512M
post_max_size = 0
upload_max_filesize = 1000M
```

What's the problem? Uploading files less than 1MB is successful but anything greater than that, Google Chrome outputs:

```
Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.
```

I already checked for the error log file but it doesn't exist in the directory. I also checked `/var/log/httpd/error_log` but no uploading related problems. I don't know anything else which might have caused the problem so I have reached out for your helping hand. Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean *greater than 1GB?* Take a look at your question's title!

Comment: uh... I meant what I meant.

Comment: hmm.. alright, sorry. You just had setup *PHP* `upload_max_filesize = 1000M` and I wouldn't think that *1MB* uploads could ever fail! Just wanted to double-check.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I discovered the problem, The problem was with [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx)

In nginx.conf:

```
http {
    client_max_body_size 0;
}
```

I set [`client_max_body_size`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#client_max_body_size) to `0`. the default was `1M`.

Comment: Thanks. Small explanaition : in the doc of nginx it's said "If the stated content length is greater than this size, then the client receives the HTTP error code 413 ("Request Entity Too Large"). It should be noted that web browsers do not usually know how to properly display such an HTTP error." http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule That's why, probably, the error message is not precise.

Comment: I might be late to the party but is there something similar that would work for Apache?

Answer (score 0):

Why is `post_max_size = 0` ?

It should be at least `1000M` in your case, since most uploads are POST requests.

Comment: isn't it that 0 is unlimited?