# Nextcloud 14 does not upload files bigger than 1MB

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, php-fpm, upload, nextcloud

I am running Nextcloud 14 on Debian Stretch with nginx, php-fpm7.2, mariadb and redis inside a LXC container (Proxmox VE, lvm thin storage). On another LXC container, alpine linux 3.8 runs an nginx reverse proxy.

For some reason i can not upload files larger than one megabyte.

I already tried/checked the following:

- php upload_max_filesize = 16G
- php post_max_size = 16G
- php output_buffering = Off
- php max_input_time = 3600
- php max_execution_time = 3600
- php memory_limit = 1024M
- php upload_tmp_dir = /upload_tmp/ (permissions and available space are fine)
- nginx client_max_body_size 16G;
- nginx fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
- nginx client_body_temp_path /upload_tmp;
- reverseproxy proxy_buffering off;
- reverseproxy proxy_request_buffering off;

Does someone have an idea, where else i could take a look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the reverse proxy. In the http block was another client_max_body_size set to 1m. Setting it to 0 solved it. Found the solution here: https://serverfault.com/a/401732/393856